# Anonymous access problem on multi-lingual website

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, publishing-site

I created a new publishing site with anonymous access enabled and it was working fine.

Then I made it multi lingual by making English and Arabic versions. You know by going to "Language Settings" and then going to "Variations" and Variation Labels". Now the site is multi lingual but with two problems.

1. I am unable to access both English and Arabic sites as anonymous user. It is asking to login.
2. On both sites there is a message in yellow bar being displayed

> Status: Checked in and viewable by authorized users. Publication Start
>   Date: Immediately

When I went to "Publish" tab of that page where this message is displayed, "Approve" and "Publish" buttons are disabled. I thought lets submit this for approval which I did by clicking on "Submit".
I am back to that page and now it says

> Status: Waiting for approval. Publication Start
>   Date: Immediately

And "Approval" button was enabled so I clicked it but got error

> There are currently no approval tasks assigned to you.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by adding another user in "Approver" group. Even though I was site collection administrator, it was not allowing me to approve. Logging as another user who has approval permission solved the problem.